# No permission for modification

Tags: facebook, react-native

I'm following the tutorial for building a React Native application, but I can't make changes in the App.js file. I'm using Brackets and I get an error saving file: The permissions do not allow you to make modifications. I followed the exact instructions on the Facebook.github website. I'm using a Mac and i'm a sudo user. I've tried installing the project again but it doesn't help. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Where are you setting up the project on your system? Perhaps it’s in some location with restricted access? Have you tested with an alternative editor to rule out an issue with Brackets?

Comment: I put it on my desktop, so that shouldn't be the problem. I haven't tried with a different editor though, I will try that.